# ASP MVC Routing - How to change the name of the default id parameter, while keeping the default route intact

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

In my ASP MVC web application, my controllers often have action with a "name" parameter, like this:

```
Function Consult(name As String) As ActionResult

    .....

    Return View()
End Function
```

I would like to be able to browse these actions the same way I would browse them with an "id" parameter: ../Book/Consult/MyBookName

But I want the default route to continue to work with "id" parameters. In other words, I would like the default route to accept either "id" or "name" as parameter name.

So I tried to configure my routes like this but it does not work as all the requests seems to use the first route and never the second. Actions with "id" parameters do not work anymore.

```
     routes.MapRoute( _
        name:="Name", _
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{name}", _
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )

    //Default Route
    routes.MapRoute( _
        name:="Default", _
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

My code examples are in VB but I will accept answers in C# as well :) Thanks a lot folks.

EDIT: To clarify,if I simply rename the parameter to "id", everything works fine with just the default route in my route config. But I would like to keep "name" as it is way more clean in these specific cases..

Comment: what type is your `id`? It's important to know this as if the `Name` route is going to come first, we want to exclude it from matching routes with ids in them, if we can (it may be the case that there exists a name that looks like an id, in which case, it will be hard for us to recognise this as a name and not an id)

Comment: Well in my case, `id` are integers, but could it be possible to keep the default route to work with any type of `id`? In the future, I might have to support string ids for example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a route constraint.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#adding_constraints_to_routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Name",
    "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
    new RouteValueDictionary 
        {{"name", "[a-zA-Z]*"}}
);
```

This should restrict the route to names that contain only letters. If the name can contain numbers, adjust the regular expression accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in the defaults:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
        name:="Name", _
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{name}", _
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

.id should match your parameter name so try:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
            name:="Name", _
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{name}", _
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .name = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
```

Comment: You are right, it was a copy-paste error. But this was not the cause of my problem. Thank you.